# When custom Adapter required?

Tags: android, adapter

> In most cases you will need to customize the Array Adapter to populate
>   the layout used for each View to represent the underlying array data.

These are the lines from a book I am reading.
But I am unable to understand why we require custom Adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below situation :
You are having a listview where each list item should have textview, an edit and delete button.
See sample listitem below :

[image]

In such case it might be a bit difficult to design the list items without using custom adapters.
The same can be achieved by designing a seperate layout for this listitem and attach this to the main list view using concept of custom adapters.

Hope you understood.
If it is not yet clear, you can ask for further clarification.

Happy coding

Comment: So In this case which will be the better approach ? making a custom adapter or designing a separate layout ?

Comment: I think making a custom adapter and designing a seperate layout ... both go together.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayAdapter` will bind the `String` representation of every object it holds to a `TextView` inside the row layout. Whenever you have more than one `View` in your row layout you'll need a custom `Adapter` or a customized version of `ArrayAdapter`. You can refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) of `ArrayAdapter` for a more detailed description of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to give the rows of a `ListView` a custom layout. It is true that you can create a layout in which you have a `TextView` and the data will bind just fine, but how would  you go about binding information to more than one `TextView`? You will need to bind this data manually using a custom `Adapter`.